# Scaling a Knapsack-Like Quandry With Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

So I have a typical recursive implementation of a problem that requires a 1-0 knapsack problem-like solution. Here's the code for the main function:

```
def knapsack(items,sizeLimit):
    P = {}

    def recurse(nItems,lim):
        if not P.has_key((nItems,lim)):
            if nItems == 0:
                P[nItems,lim] = 0
            elif itemSize(items[nItems-1]) > lim:
                P[nItems,lim] = recurse(nItems-1,lim)
            else:
                P[nItems,lim] = max(recurse(nItems-1,lim),
                    recurse(nItems-1,lim-itemSize(items[nItems-1])) +
                    itemValue(items[nItems-1]))
        return P[nItems,lim]

    return recurse(len(items),sizeLimit)
```

The problem is that I have millions upon millions of pieces of data, and it seems like this approach will calculate every entry, leading to obvious memory and speed problems. Is there some kind of dynamic programming/memoization technique I could use to further optimize this implementation?

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to find with the algorithm? Something like "I want to find optimal XXX so that YYY is maximized" Also some upper limit on the parameter to the algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly are you asking for. It is already a top-down DP solution.

Comment: So it can't be further optimized with other DP techniques? I'm trying to find optimal song lengths so that the value of certain other metadata is maximized.

Comment: You can make it more space efficient by not using recursion.  Have you looked at the algorithm on the Wikipedia page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem

Comment: @VaughnCato: Why do you claim it will be "more space efficient", because of the `O(n)` space saved for the stack trace? The space complexity of both solutions is `O(n*W)` (where in this case `W = lim`). The iterative DP algorithm is basically a buttom-up DP solution of the same recursive formula.

Comment: @amit: You can iterate over the item counts and re-use the same array, only indexed by weight instead of being indexed by both weight and item count.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Yes, but note that will only give you the optimal solution (number), and you will not be able to reproduce your steps to get a feasible optimal solution for this number, which can be done later on with `P` (which I assume what the OP is after, could be wrong though).

Comment: I think knapsack is np-hard ... and will take essentially full exploration :/  there are greedy solutions that usually yield the best solution but will fail occasionally ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have problems when scaling your problem
take a look at [this dir](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/mhampton/sage-4.7.2.alpha2-sage.math.washington.edu-x86_64-Linux/devel/sage-main/build/sage/numerical/) example in specific [this file](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/mhampton/sage-4.7.2.alpha2-sage.math.washington.edu-x86_64-Linux/devel/sage-main/build/sage/numerical/knapsack.py)

The following is taken from given url:

If your knapsack problem is composed of three items (weight, value)
defined by (1,2), (1.5,1), (0.5,3), and a bag of maximum weight 2,
you can easily solve it this way::

```
sage: from sage.numerical.knapsack import knapsack
sage: knapsack( [(1,2), (1.5,1), (0.5,3)], max=2)
[5.0, [(1, 2), (0.500000000000000, 3)]]
```

Super-increasing sequences

We can test for whether or not a sequence is super-increasing::

```
sage: from sage.numerical.knapsack import Superincreasing
sage: L = [1, 2, 5, 21, 69, 189, 376, 919]
sage: seq = Superincreasing(L)
sage: seq
Super-increasing sequence of length 8
sage: seq.is_superincreasing()
True
sage: Superincreasing().is_superincreasing([1,3,5,7])
False
```

Solving the subset sum problem for a super-increasing sequence
and target sum::

```
sage: L = [1, 2, 5, 21, 69, 189, 376, 919]
sage: Superincreasing(L).subset_sum(98)
[69, 21, 5, 2, 1]
```

"""

Also, there is one from [Number Jack](http://www.hakank.org/numberjack/), to [test this](http://www.hakank.org/numberjack/knapsack.py) you will have to import all necesary files.